# Material flutter app source code

Tags: dart, flutter

There used to be a sample application, called Material flutter. It was a nice show case of all the flutter widgets. Does anyone knows where the source code is?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The source code for the Flutter Gallery demo application is at:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/master/examples/flutter_gallery/

Answer (score 0):

there are some example projects in your flutter install location located in the examples folder.